# WPF Disable listbox items with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, datatrigger

I tried searching through a lot of threads and I've found several that's pretty close but not exactly what I want.  After a day of searching, I just decided to ask.  Apologies if I missed something, I feel like this would be common enough but I can't seem to quite get it.

I have UserControl that bounded to a ViewModel, and it has a Listbox with ItemsSource=ObservableCollection which is a property of the ViewModel like below:

Whenever I select an item, I call SomeObject.IsEnabled = false on several other items depending on certain conditions.  I'd like to bind the listbox items to that IsEnabled property so I can grayout whichever items whenever I do a selection.

ViewModel:

```
Class ViewModel : PropertyNotificationObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<SomeObject> m_list;
    public ObservableCollection<SomeObject> List {get; set;} //notifying properly

    private void selectedItem()
    {
        //several in SomeObjects in List sets IsEnabled = false
    }
}
```

The Object Class

```
class SomeObject : PropertyNotificationObject
{
   private bool m_isEnabled;
   public IsEnabled { get; set; } //notifying properly
}
```

XAML

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="ListTemplate">
    <Grid>
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding ., Converter={someConverterObjectToString}}"/>
    </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding List}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListTemplate}"/>
```

I've tried using StyleTriggers in the ListBox.ItemContainerStyle and the DataTemplate like below but I couldn't figure out how to get to the SomeOject.IsEnabled property.

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding={???????? I can't get to my SomeObject properties.}
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Sorry for the lack of colors, I'm new here and don't really know how use the editor very well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to bind the enabled property.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`{Binding IsEnabled}` in your `ItemContainerStyle` should do the work. Look at VS debug window for binding errors

**Edit** or directly bind the IsEnabled property of the ListBoxItem:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: That did it!  I saw this in a lot of examples but I realized I was expecting to see my IsEnabled property in intellisense when I was doing "Value=Binding{}" and never did so assumed my binding was wrong.  This binding is reflected so it's obvious it won't have intellisense for it.  I feel like an idiot now.

Comment: As an aside: Intellisense for XAML Bindings is not featured by Visual Studio. You will need an add on (such as Resharper 6) for that.